# Apache httpd.conf rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some rewrite rules in my httpd.conf file. Is there a way to get apache to check the rewrite rules only if the url is not valid? My rewrite rules are preceded by checks for the REQUEST_FILENAME being a valid file, and a valid folder. But the documentation mentions that the rewrite conditions are checked only AFTER it finds a match for the rewrite rule.

So, whenever there is a request for a URL, apache checks each rewrite rule for that URL. Almost all the pages have images, .js and .css files and a few more files with them. Apache checks those too, against the rewrite rules in the httpd.conf (I see this in the RewriteLog generated for each URL). This significantly slows down the site.

I am aware of the FallbackResource directive. I don't want to use it as of now, because it returns a http status code of 200 by default. I want to return the correct status code (usually a 301) whenever there is a request for a page that was not found by Apache (usually, the incorrect URL has a correct counterpart, hence the need to send a 301). Sending the correct http status code also benefits our seo efforts. If there is a way to send the correct http status code using the FallbackResource directive, I would be open to using that option.

I have tried googling for these issues, and didn't find an answer. I have tried with different RewriteCond (s) but, like the documentation says, each rewriterule is checked anyways.

Any pointers on this would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that there'd be some readings to do for you but, I always use this as "bible" when it comes to rewrite rule and haven't ceased to failed me.  Perhaps this would do the same for you.

http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /not-found.php [L]
```

I would put in a .htaccess file located in the root folder. That way you can easily customize it for each site.